# How to get indices of top k values for each (selected) column in data.table

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

How to find the indices of the top k (say k=3) values for each column

```
> dt <- data.table( x = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1) )
> dt
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 3 1
4: 1 2
5: 3 2
6: 1 1
7: 1 1
```

Required output:

```
> output.1
   x y
1: 1 2
2: 3 4
3: 5 5
```

Or even better (notice the additional helpful descending sort in x):

```
> output.2
   var top1 top2 top3
1:   x    3    5    1
2:   y    2    4    5
```

Having the output would be already a great help.

Comment: do you care about the order of equally ranked values? like: `x | 5 | 3 | 7; y | 5 | 4 | 2;`

Comment: @jangorecki, yes, I would rather keep the order of equally ranked values, but this is not an absolute must. Regardless of my personal need here, it is a good habit to preserve the original order for easier debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `sort` (with `index.return=TRUE`) after looping over the columns of the dataset with `lapply`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sort(head(sort(x, 
          decreasing=TRUE, index.return=TRUE)$ix,3)))]
#   x y
#1: 1 2
#2: 3 4
#3: 5 5
```

Or use `order`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sort(head(order(-x),3)))]
```

Comment: Nice one, forgot about `index.return=TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

If the order of the elements having same rank doesn't matter then this answer would be also valid.
The order information can be extracted from data.table index.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(x = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
set2key(dt, x)
set2key(dt, y)

tail.index = function(dt, index, n){
    idx = attr(attr(dt, "index"), index)
    rev(tail(idx, n))
}

tail.index(dt, "__x", 3L)
#[1] 5 3 7
tail.index(dt, "__y", 3L)
#[1] 5 4 2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg you speak about `7 <-> 1` ? note they have same value so their rank is the same - which is noted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose solution which I'm sure undermines the slickness of the `data.table` package:

```
dt$idx <- seq.int(1:nrow(dt))

k <- 3

top_x <- dt[order(-x), idx[1:k]]
top_y <- dt[order(-y), idx[1:k]]

dt_top <- data.table(top_x, top_y)

dt_top
#    top_x top_y
# 1:     3     2
# 2:     5     4
# 3:     1     5
```